# Youtube video embed can't fullscreen in Colorbox

Tags: youtube, colorbox

today I wanted to learn about colorbox and video embeded inside of it but I got a problem about can't go fullscreen video.. It says "Full Screen is unavailable"..

this is my screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to youtube and grab your code to embed it, it gives you the code for `iframe` and in that code there is an attribute `allowfullscreen`.

The problem for me was fixed by instead typing `allowFullScreen` with a capital `F` and `S`.

And for others they had to add ='true'. So `allowFullScreen="true"` or just try `allowFullScreen`